# SELECT TOP 1 result from table ordered by field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this :

```
id               package               start_date            option
1                342323                2012-02-02            1
2                3423333               2012-02-06            1
3                552234                2012-02-14            2
```

I want to select only the `(top 1)` row that has the `minimum start_date`.

I tried `where start_date = MIN(start_date)` but it's not working.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top 1 * from table
order by start_date
```

Comment: thank you... I didn;t realize this ... so .. to use it in a join .. I have to do `cross apply` right ?

Comment: @pufos I'm not sure what to answer... you can just do `select * from tbl1 join (this_query) s`... That's quite a general question :)

Comment: if I use `join (select top 1 * ...)` it won;t return anything : because of `top 1` ...

Comment: Actually, it isn't probably necessary to join against one record. I think you should create another question providing details on what you're trying to achieve and then we can further help you. PS: The join will retrieve all matching records from tbl1 and the query result.

Comment: I have this table that I want to add (join) to a query but I need the `package` for the lowest `date`

Comment: Then, you don't even need a join. Take a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e586/1)

Answer (score 1):

For Sql server

```
 select top 1 * from tbl_name order by start_date
```

For Mysql

```
 select * from tbl_name order by start_date asc limit 1
```

Comment: Actually, this is valid in MySQL and PostgreSQL and not in SQL Server :(

Comment: that was for the original post

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
where start_date = (select min(start_date) from yourtable)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY start_date ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Actually, this is valid in MySQL and PostgreSQL and not in SQL Server :(

Comment: @MostyMostacho You're true, but user updated the question after our answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from Yourtable 
WHERE start_date = (SELECT (Min(yt1.Start_Date) FROM YourTable as yt1)
```

Comment: Why do you do two select? With `TOP` and `LIMIT` you can obtain the same result, in a efficient way...

Comment: fully agreed, but I supposed that this can a little part of big select, in this case there is possiblity that TOP and LIMIT can be unusable

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL

```
select top 1 * from your_table order by start_date asc
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL Server-specific query should get you the data you want. Try using this:

```
select top 1 * from tbl_name order by start_date asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
;With top_record as 
(
 SELECt *
  ,row_number() OVER (order by start_date ASC) as row
  FROM yourtable
)
SELECT * from top_record WHERE row = 1
```

This would then give you the flexibility to determine what to do with ties by using DENSE_RANK / RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER()